# It there a way to monitor Android system api calls?

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin

I want to monitor several system functions like `displayMetrics.heightPixel`, `Build.DISPLAY` or access to the Accelerometer/Gyroscope for arbitrary Apps running on the system.
The goal is to log those function calls into a file.

Is there a way to monitor it, without reimplementing Android?
Do any of you know a good approach for that ?

Comment: No.  Those two aren't even system calls-  Build is an object created by the app.  DisplayMetrics may have a system call somewhere in the chain, but accessing individual fields on it are again an object read.  Registering for sensors is the only one that actually is a system call.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how I would monitor them without patching these functions for every app ?

Comment: If you're talking about a custom AOSP build you could patch the framework.  If you mean on a random device I don't think you could.

Comment: I mean, Build for example comes from the Android.os library. As far as I understand it, I would need to modify the android.so library or recompile it to log function calls. Is there an easier way ?